# Rsync to Amazon Linux EC2 instance - failed: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rsync

I want to upload the content of one directory to my Amazon EC2 with rsync:

```
rsync -r -t -v --progress -z -s -e "ssh -i /home/mostafa/keyamazon.pem" /home/mostafa/splitfiles ubuntu@ec2-64-274-161-87.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~/splitfiles
```

but I receive the following error message:

```
sending incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/home/mostafa/splitfiles" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir#3 "/home/ubuntu//~" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(712) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

and if I do a dry run with grsync, it works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completed this task with Filezilla instead, easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

In rsync the trailing / is very important. Also you rsync usually defaults to ssh when one of the destinations contains a host.

So you if you want to preserver modification times then you can get rid of the -e and -s options.

Your command could be written as /home/mostafa/splitfiles/ ubuntu@ec2-64-274-161-87.compute-1.amazonaws.com:splitfiles/ - notice the trailing /'s provided that you have ssh configured to read the private key from your home directory.

On ubuntu you can add this to the key chain, by going

```
ssh-add [key-file]
```

And this will save you having to specify the keyfile everytime you ssh into the AWS machine.

The errors seem to say that on the local machine you don't have a source directory and the destination doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are at home ~ if you cd ../ to root you will be able to run the command.